# Set Analysis date, 2 conditions, max date - 1

Tags: database, report, visualization, qlikview, set-analysis

I have a set analysis and need to restrict the range of the maxmim date to -1 -

=max({<BREAK={'5Days'}>}date(DATE))

I tried like this but I have an error -

```
=max({<BREAK={'5Days'}, DATE = {Today()-1}>}date(DATE)) and

=max({<BREAK={'5Days'}>+< DATE = {Today()-1}>}date(DATE))
```

Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Im not sure what the problem is. Possible to share small data example?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this -

```
=max({<BREAK={'5Days'}>}date((DATE)-1))
```

and it worked perfectly. In fact it gave the maximum date - 1.